# Client server communication: REST vs Socket architecture

Tags: rest, sockets, websocket, client-server

What are the advantages and disadvantages of using **only** socket based communication vs a hybrid of REST and socket (using socket only when bidirectional communication is necessary, like receiving messages in a chat).

When I say only socket, I mean that instead of sending a GET request asking for `/entities`, I'd send `update_needed` and the server would send a push via socket.

My question is not really about performance, it's more about the concept, like `delegate` vs `block/lambda` (using socket would be like the delegate concept and REST is more like block).

Answer (score 1):

It all boils down to what type of application and level of scalability you have in mind.

[WebSocket/REST: Client connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29145970/websocket-rest-client-connections/29149314)

[How to handle CQRS from a client-side perspective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24429933/how-to-handle-cqrs-from-a-client-side-perspective/24430455)

[Hard downsides of long polling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21676324/hard-downsides-of-long-polling)

Comment: My question is not really about performance, it's more about the concept, like delegate vs block/lambda

Answer (score 0):

The main reason why I wouldn't use WebSockets in any major project is simply that still many users don't use a modern browser that support them. Namely IE 8 and 9 [don't support them](http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets) and both together still have a market share of over 20 % (Oct 15).

Comment: Let's say the client is an iOS app

Comment: If you are building a modern web application, people using IE 8 and 9 will suffer other major limitations beyond websockets https://people.mozilla.org/~prouget/ie9/