# Problems when synchronising objects via WebSockets?

Tags: javascript, websocket

I'd like to synchronise data between a browser client and server using ONLY WebSockets.

Currently most people use WebSockets only to notify the client that some data is available on the server.

After investigating the current state I found no good reasons why I wouldn't use WebSockets to synchronise the data directly.

*Note:* This is not a duplicate of [disadvantages of websockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224771/disadvantages-of-websockets) as I've got a specific use case in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely no technical problem in doing so. The problem is if you try to decouple writes and reads to move to a more scalable architecture like CQRS. Are websockets part of the reads or the writes? :)

My recomendation for regular apps is to use WebSockets to get updates, and to send queries about the read model like autocompletion inputs, searches, etc... But use a REST API to send actual data that needs to be persisted. But, if you application is highly interactive then you will never find yourself in a position of wanting to decouple reads and writes, so using WebSockets for all should be fine.

[How to handle CQRS from a client-side perspective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24429933/how-to-handle-cqrs-from-a-client-side-perspective/24430455)

[WebSocket/REST: Client connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29145970/websocket-rest-client-connections/29149314)

Answer (score 1):

I've done that using SSE without any particular issue (just make sure you read data updates on a single channel, i.e. don't send a response payload with a REST call *and* the same payload over your persistent channel), and I think WebSockets should be even better. Can't imagine why it wouldn't work (as long as there's no old HTTP proxy screwing up WebSockets itself).